# How to plot polar historgram?

Tags: python, plot

I have the data of azimuth and the magnitude of the earth property and would like to plot it on the polar azimuthal histrogram (like a rose diagram)

This is the excerpt of the data:

```py
degrees         velocity
22.44903    9449.275
22.4512     9474.46
22.45321    9717.624
22.45537    9745.26
22.45739    9746.532
22.45953    9372.272
22.46157    9899.907
22.46369    9499.646
22.46581    9856.678
22.46786    9811.213
22.46999    9765.846
22.47202    9814.11
22.47418    9974.829
22.47619    10162.89
```

This is what I have tried, but it produces the plot that is not similar to the one I have expected:

```py
from physt import histogram, binnings, special
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = genfromtxt(file, delimiter=',')

x=data[:,0]
y=data[:,1]
hist = special.polar_histogram(x, y)
ax = hist.plot.polar_map()
```

I suspect there could be a problem with conversion of coordinates. What I want is simply distribution (histogram) of values plotted along the azimuth axis

Comment: What is `special`? I suggest adding the `import` statements to it is clear what packages you are using. If `special` is your own code, then it is quite important to add for this question.

Comment: Did you convert angle from degrees to radians?

Comment: I have tried converting, but still the same

Answer (score 0):

Try with seaborn pakage

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(x,y)
```